# Is it possible to turn off default mappings completely using entity framework code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I want to do all my mappings using the fluent API and I don't want any properties that I miss (they may be properties that aren't persisted for example) to be mapping using the default rules. Is there any way to turn off auto mapping globally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable automapping of properties in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607591/how-to-disable-automapping-of-properties-in-entity-framework)

Comment: Please take a look at @baHl response here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42653822/1927444

Comment: @r1verside - thanks for that, so  it looks like I need to ignore each property individually